# Recursive List Creation Function. Errors in type

Tags: recursion, ocaml

I have an Ocaml function that is giving me errors.

What I am trying to do:

Recursively create a List of random numbers (0-2) of size "limit".

Here's what I have:

```
let rec carDoorNumbers = fun limit -> 
match limit with
| [1] -> Random.int 3
| [] -> Random.int 3 :: carDoorNumbers (limit-1);;
```

I am getting this error:

```
Error: This expression has type 'a list
   but an expression was expected of type int
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think about what your function has to do: given a limit, you have to create a *list* of numbers. So your type is something like `carDoorNumbers : int -> int list`.

Looking at that, it seems you have two errors. First, you're matching `limit` (which should be an `int`) against a list pattern. `[1] -> ...` matches a list containing only the element `1` and `[]` matches the empty list; you really want to match against the number `1` and any other number `n`.

The second error is that you return two different types in your `match` statement. Remember that you are supposed to be returning a list. In the first case, you are returning `Random.int 3`, which is an `int` rather than an `int list`. What you really want to return here is something like `[Random.int 3]`.

The error you got is a little confusing. Since the first thing you returned was an `int`, it expects your second thing to *also* be an `int`. However, your second case was actually correct: you *do* return an `int list`! However, the compiler does not know what you meant, so its error is backwards; rather than changing the `int list` to an `int`, you need to change the `int` to an `int list`.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. For my second case, instead of comparing to an empty list [], how would I just use it for all other possibilities for limit (I assume its a pos. #)?

Comment: The argument is a number. You want to match *any* number (except 1, but that gets matched by the previous case). You can do this with the simplest pattern `n`, which matches anything and binds it to the variable `n`. (You can naturally name the variable whatever you want.)

Answer (score 2):

Your `match` expression treats limit like a list.  Both `[1]` and `[]` are lists.  That's what the compiler is telling you.  But it seems limit should be an integer.

To match an integer, just use an integer constant.  No square brackets.

(As a side comment, you might want to be sure the function works well when you pass it 0.)

Comment: Yea I definitely am not accounting for all inputs, assuming pos. integers. Thanks, I'll take out the brackets. How do I make the second case run for every possible "limit" except 1? The more I think about it the more I think I need if/else statements.

Comment: The "wild card" pattern is `_`, which will work for this code.  There's no harm at all in using `if/then/else` in OCaml.  That's what I usually use for ints.